# How to display an li tag's title using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, title

I recently found a javascript image gallery, and noticed that it changes the title attribute in the `<li>` tag. I was wondering how I could make the title information display as text, and update dynamically. As always, any help is appreciated. The code is below.

Thanks,

Mraisky

JS:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<style media="screen,projection" type="text/css">
    #jgal li { filter: alpha(opacity=50); }
    #jgal li.active, #jgal li:hover { filter: alpha(opacity=100); }
</style>
<![endif]-->
<!--[if lt IE 6]><style media="screen,projection" type="text/css">#gallery { display: block; }</style><![endif]-->
<script type="text/javascript">document.write("<style type='text/css'> #gallery { display: none; } </style>");</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var gal = {
    init: function () {
        if (!document.getElementById || !document.createElement || !document.appendChild) return false;
        if (document.getElementById('gallery')) document.getElementById('gallery').id = 'jgal';
        var li = document.getElementById('jgal').getElementsByTagName('li');
        li[0].className = 'active';
        for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
            li[i].style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + li[i].getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src + ')';
            li[i].title = li[i].getElementsByTagName('img')[0].alt;
            gal.addEvent(li[i], 'click', function () {
                var im = document.getElementById('jgal').getElementsByTagName('li');
                for (j = 0; j < im.length; j++) {
                    im[j].className = '';
                }
                this.className = 'active';
            });
        }
    },
    addEvent: function (obj, type, fn) {
        if (obj.addEventListener) {
            obj.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
        }
        else if (obj.attachEvent) {
            obj["e" + type + fn] = fn;
            obj[type + fn] = function () {
                obj["e" + type + fn](window.event);
            }
            obj.attachEvent("on" + type, obj[type + fn]);
        }
    }
}
gal.addEvent(window, 'load', function () {
    gal.init();
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="gallery">
<li><img src="images/paintings/image1.jpg" alt="Pennsylvania Ave./Linda --- 2006 --- oil and wallpaper on canvas"></li>
<li><img src="images/paintings/image2.jpg" alt="Mt. Vernon Ave. I --- 2007 --- oil and wallpaper on canvas"></li>
<li><img src="images/paintings/image3.jpg" alt="Northland, I --- 2006 --- oil and wallpaper on canvas"></li>
<li><img src="images/paintings/image4.jpg" alt="S.H.S./ Page. Arizonia --- 2007 --- oil on canvas"></li>
<li><img src="images/paintings/image5.jpg" alt="California/ Gum Tree --- 2005 --- oil and wallpaper on canvas"></li>
<li><img src="images/paintings/image6.jpg" alt="Oak Park Park, from Mexico love, Jennifer --- 2006"></li>
<li><img src="images/paintings/image7.jpg" alt="New Orleans Mall to Bryce Canyon --- 2006 --- oil on canvas"></li>
<li><img src="images/paintings/image8.jpg" alt="Hilton to Pierce Ave --- 2005 --- oil on canvas"></li>
<li><img src="images/paintings/image9.jpg" alt="Penn. Ave. Hear No Evil, Speak No Evil, See No Evil --- 2006 --- oil and wallpaper on canvas"></li>
<li><img src="images/paintings/image10.jpg" alt="Oak Park Park/Marlas House --- 2007 --- oil and wallpaper on canvas"></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Why do people not indent JavaScript? Aargh!

Comment: @Skilldrick To make it feel more "scripty"

Comment: Sorry, It got messed up when I posted it

Comment: http://jsbeautifier.org/

Comment: I don't really get what your posted javascript code is going to do. Couldn't you post us a working example? How is that HTML created? Couldn't you justadd a title attribute to the A or the LI? Which gallery function do you use? There are many out there that will show the image title automatically. Where do you want to show the text of the alt attribute?

Comment: I am trying to add captions to this slideshow: http://www.deborahsukenic.com/gallery.html

Answer (score 0):

OK, within the the `gal.addEvent(li[i], 'click', function (){`  function do the following:

```
document.getElementById('caption').innerHTML = this.alt;
```

Than you just need an element for that caption:

```
<div id="caption"></div>
```

Is this what you want to have?

Comment: Yes, but when I test this the text in the caption div returns "undefined". The code now is:

            gal.addEvent(li[i], 'click', function () {
                var im = document.getElementById('jgal').getElementsByTagName('li');
                for (j = 0; j < im.length; j++) {
                    im[j].className = '';
                }
                this.className = 'active';
                document.getElementById('caption').innerHTML = img.alt;
            });

Comment: When I step through the javascript, the im function is undefined

Comment: I thought `im` would be the image. Pleae see my changes above.

Comment: Ok, now I have it. It is `this` (the element you are clicked on)

Answer (score 0):

I finally figured it out. I used the caption div that Kau-Boy suggested, then changed the javascript to the following:

```
    var gal = {
    init: function () {
        if (!document.getElementById || !document.createElement || !document.appendChild) return false;
        if (document.getElementById('gallery')) document.getElementById('gallery').id = 'jgal';
        var li = document.getElementById('jgal').getElementsByTagName('li');
        li[0].className = 'active';
        var captions =  li[0].getElementsByTagName('img')[0].alt;
        document.getElementById('caption').innerHTML = captions;
        for (i = 0; i < li.length; i++) {
            li[i].style.backgroundImage = 'url(' + li[i].getElementsByTagName('img')[0].src + ')';
            li[i].title = li[i].getElementsByTagName('img')[0].alt;
            gal.addEvent(li[i], 'click', function () {
                var im = document.getElementById('jgal').getElementsByTagName('li');
                for (j = 0; j < im.length; j++) {
                    im[j].className = '';
                }
                this.className = 'active';
                var captions = this.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].alt;
                document.getElementById('caption').innerHTML = captions;
            });
        }
    },
    addEvent: function (obj, type, fn) {
        if (obj.addEventListener) {
            obj.addEventListener(type, fn, false);
        }
        else if (obj.attachEvent) {
            obj["e" + type + fn] = fn;
            obj[type + fn] = function () {
                obj["e" + type + fn](window.event);
            }
            obj.attachEvent("on" + type, obj[type + fn]);
        }
    }
}
gal.addEvent(window, 'load', function () {
    gal.init();
});
```